# MicroSD not showing because of corruption

Tags: windows-8, micro-sd-card

I have a Dell Venue 8 Pro a few months ago which runs on full Windows 8.1 and I put a MicroSD 64GB (Kingston SDCX10) on it's MicroSD card slot and it is working properly. Today my cat tripped my tablet and fall solidly at it's corner, denting it and somewhat messes with the SD card, the tablet seems to be working just fine after the fall.

I suspect that it corrupts my SD card since I have enabled the Write-Caching Policy on that device and the fall might have removed the SD card unexpectedly. I tried inserting a different MicroSD on my tablet and it is just working fine so it is not on the slot itself.

What was happening when I insert my MicroSD card again is that nothing shows up on My Computer and the device isn't visible at all. I tried using CMD to chkdsk the drive but it just shows the 'Cannot open volume for direct access.' error.

Is there anything I can do to fix my SD card?

**Update** BlackBerry devices seems to recognize my SD card but cannot format or read it at all so it seems that was just on the card's corrupted BIOS or something. Are there any application for windows that can make it recognize and format such corruption?

Comment: It sounds like the card may have been physically damaged;  try it in another device. Unfortunately, it has to be seen in some way by some system before you can try to recover it if it has been corrupted.

Comment: @Debra I doubt the card would be physically damaged since it hadn't physically been removed by the fall. I read that blackberry device can detect such corruption, but still cannot read it. I have tried it on my android device and also tried it using a adapter and a card reader but it hasn't been detected at all. I'll ask my brother who has bb when he come home tomorrow to try my card on his CP.

Comment: If multiple systems/devices can't detect the card at all, then that card is (most likely) busted and need to be replaced.

Comment: @techie007 My brother's bb can detect my SD card but cannot read it. Is there a software that I can use to detect and format my SD card on Windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you originally only tried to look at the card in something like Windows Explorer, and not with Windows Disk Management. Only the latter will show you unformatted devices;  Windows Explorer won't recognize media until it has been formatted to one of the storage systems that your version of Windows recognizes.

Since your updated post shows that the card is visible on a Blackberry, you can try any of the common recovery tools for SD cards.  There is an article here which lists 6 such: http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9224577/6_data_recovery_tools_for_SD_cards_USB_drives_and_more

Of those, I have used Recuva, with success.  It is relatively easy to use and, best of all, is free.  However, that's a personal recommendation, which is not the purpose here.  All of these tools are capable of recovering data from a card that has been corrupted.

Unfortunately, I can't walk you through a recovery process without knowing which tool you choose, but most of them are relatively intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use DiskPart to delete and repartition the entire drive. I've had luck with it in the past.

Type the following commands in an admin command prompt:

1. **diskpart**
2. **list disk** (find your thumb drive by looking at the size column)
3. **Select disk N** (the disk number of your thumb drive)
4. **list partition**
5. **select partition N** (the number of the partition you want to delete)
6. **delete partition** (repeat steps 5 and 6 to remove all partitions listed in step 4)
7. **create partition primary [size=N]** (N is the total size of the thumb drive as listed in step 3)
8. **select partition 1**
9. **active**
10. **assign** (gives the SD card the next available drive letter)

close command prompt and try to access drive. Be careful on step three, picking the wrong drive could result in you wiping out your boot drive partitions(very bad).

Comment: Thanks, but the drive isn't visible at all at step 2. The only visible drive is my internal drive (Drive 0) even when my SD card is inserted.

Comment: You may somehow scraped that SD card then, normally any connected drives will appear. It seems like the system is not even recognizing the card, so it is most likely toast.

Comment: :'( I'll try if my brothers BB can detect it, if it didn't then i'll just give up. I was hoping that it was just on the SD card's buffers or something.